# how to extract string starting with a sequence and ending with a space from a long string

Tags: python

I have a string as following:

```
ERROR2208 ERROR2209 ERROR2210 occurred upon initialization
```

I need to get all the ERROR tokens as a list from this string. What is the best way to do this in python?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.split()` to get a list of words, and then use `filter()` with `.startswith()` to extract only the words starting with `"ERROR"`:

```py
data = "ERROR2208 ERROR2209 ERROR2210 occurred upon initialization"

tokens = data.split(" ")
error_tokens = list(filter(lambda x: x.startswith("ERROR"), tokens))
print(error_tokens)
```

If the words are not necessarily separated by a space, you can use a regular expression (searching for `"ERROR"`, followed by a series of numbers, followed by a non-alphanumeric character):

```py
import re

data = "ERROR2208:ERROR2209,ERROR2210 occurred upon initialization"

pattern = re.compile(r'(ERROR\d+)[^A-Za-z0-9]')
error_tokens = re.findall(pattern, data)

print(error_tokens)
```

Answer (score 2):

Split the string on spaces, then find words that start with Error:

```
my_string = "ERROR2208 ERROR2209 ERROR2210 occurred upon initialization"

def get_error(msg):
    for word in msg.split():
        if word.startswith("ERROR"):
            yield word

print(list(get_error(my_string)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions.

```
import re

error_msg = "ERROR2208 ERROR2209 ERROR2210 occurred upon initialization"

errors_list = re.findall(r"ERROR\d+", error_msg)
print(errors_list)
```

If you just want the error numbers, then

```
errors_list = re.findall(r"ERROR(\d+)", error_msg)
```

Comment: What does this add to the discussion that my answer doesn't already cover?

Comment: Mh, If error code is of 5 digits you'll capture only first four. Anyway, I didn't answer because I wanted to correct this, but just because I only saw non-regex answers. Don't get mad

Comment: I like that there's four answers describing two approaches all written at almost exactly the same time. It's like we're a barbershop quartet.

Comment: I posted several minutes before you so I don't know how you "didn't see" any regex answers...